# Calculate average using mapreduce in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a collection of 10 million records which resembles this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596dd10bbd1a6628ace1c14c"),
    "X" : 13212,
    "Z" : 173836,
    "userID" : 9354785
}
```

User ID is unique. I have to calculate the average of X and sum of Z. I can calculate the sum of Z using the following mapReduce function

```
var mapFunction1 = function() {
emit(this.userID, this.Z);
};

var reduceFunction1 = function() {
return Array.sum(Z);
};

db.transaction.mapReduce(
mapfunction1, 
reduceFunction1,
{out:"mapreduce"}
)
```

How do i calculate the average of X?

I tried Array.avg(Z) but it returns the same output as sum(Z).

Comment: The title says "Hadoop" MapReduce, but the example looks like a MongoDB MapReduce.  Can you please clarify the question?  Is there any Hadoop involvement, or is this a MongoDB question?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the requirements can be expressed more simply using the [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) with the [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operators.

### Input

```
> db.transactions.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5970e59e26507421fa20bee9"), "X" : 13212, "Z" : 173836, "userID" : 9354785 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5970e5a426507421fa20beea"), "X" : 1234, "Z" : 5678, "userID" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5970e5a826507421fa20beeb"), "X" : 100, "Z" : 200, "userID" : 2 }
```

### Aggregation Pipeline

```
> db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id: "aggregates",
            avgX: {
                $avg: "$X"
            },
            sumZ: {
                $sum: "$Z"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

### Output

```
{ "_id" : "aggregates", "avgX" : 4848.666666666667, "sumZ" : 179714 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing (key,value) pair parameter to reduceFunction1.
Try this:

```
var mapFunction1 = function() {
emit(this.userID, this.Z);
};

var reduceFunction1 = function(varKey,varZ) {
return Array.avg(varZ);
};

db.transaction.mapReduce(
mapfunction1, 
reduceFunction1,
{out:"mapreduce"}
)
```